# How do I avoid race conditions when appending to a file?

Tags: linux, file, shell, append, race-condition

I'm looking at using [PipelineDB](https://www.pipelinedb.com/) for analytics. For data warehousing I want to append all new data to a file, and `tail -F` it into `psql` like the examples on the website.

I have multiple data sources, so to get deterministic results, I'd like to append them all to the same input file, where they'll stay in the same order.

Is there a simple, idiomatic way of avoiding race conditions? Something like a single-file server I can pipe data to?

Edit:

Actually, a race condition is exactly what I **want**. But each line must be atomic, so no single line is ever corrupted. Lines may be interleaved, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could prepend/wrap all your writes with a mutex by using GNU Parallel like this:

```
sem --id atomicwrite echo hi >> file
```

So, to test it, run each of these in separate terminals:

```
for i in {0..999}; do sem --id atomicwrite echo hi >> file ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a mutex by using mkdir which is atomic create-and-check operation (this is ensured at the kernel level):

```
# locking example -- CORRECT
# Bourne
lockdir=/tmp/myscript.lock
if mkdir "$lockdir"
then    # directory did not exist, but was created successfully
    echo >&2 "successfully acquired lock: $lockdir"
    # continue script
else
    echo >&2 "cannot acquire lock, giving up on $lockdir"
    exit 0
fi
```

For more information (and other solutions) take a look to the FAQ:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045

Comment: Preferably, I would want my scripts to run concurrently.

Comment: Then an other option is to use named pipes for synchronization.